# I get exception when I wrote valid id

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping

After starting the application(there is no problem code run successfully) when I enter a valid id for calling my entity application gives this log. I try to solve it but I couldn't find the answer.

Application log after I enter id(valid id)

2022-08-25 14:21:35.603  INFO 14956 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.learnspring.model.Student
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1643) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1627) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4521) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4511) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:539) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2835) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2768) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3367) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:an]


org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy108.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.learnspring.service.StudentService.getStudentbyId(StudentService.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.learnspring.controller.StudentController.get(StudentController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    
    2022-08-25 14:21:35.610 ERROR 14956 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.learnspring.model.Student; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.learnspring.model.Student] with root cause
    
    org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.learnspring.model.Student
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:705) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1643) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1627) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4521) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4511) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:539) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2835) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2768) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3367) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at ...
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
            at 
    ...
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:an]
```

And this is the log when I enter(invalid id doesn't exist in the database)

```
2022-08-25 14:26:13.190  WARN 14956 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

My controller class

```
import com.example.learnspring.model.StudentDTO;
import com.example.learnspring.service.StudentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class StudentController {


    @Autowired
    private  StudentService service;
 @GetMapping("/student/{id}")
    public StudentDTO get(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getStudentbyId(id);
    }}
```

Mapper class

```
import com.example.learnspring.model.Student;
import com.example.learnspring.model.StudentDTO;
import org.mapstruct.InjectionStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.ReportingPolicy;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR,
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,
        unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface StudentMapper {
    StudentDTO toDto(Student student);

}
```

And service class

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private StudentMapper studentMapper;

    public StudentDTO getStudentbyId(int id) {

        StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO();

        Optional<Student> student = repository.findById(id);
        if (student.isPresent()) {
            return studentMapper.toDto(student.get());
        }
        return studentDTO;
    }

}
```

Student

```
package com.example.learnspring.model;

import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level= AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    @NotNull(message = "Age cannot be null")
    @Min(value = 15, message = "Age should not be less than 15")
    @Max(value = 65, message = "Age should not be greater than 65")
    private int age;

    public Student(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

StudentDTO

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentDTO {

    private String name;
    private int age;

}
```

Comment: You might want to add some of your code to understand what exactly you are doing

Comment: "No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.learnspring.model.Student" - That should already tell you what the problem is - at least where: the `Student` class. Does that class have an accessible no-argument constructor?

Comment: @Thomas yes it has also I added both student and studentDto classes

Comment: please share the class then for us to check

Comment: @Thomas already added!

Comment: @DeadSilent You said "Yes it has" when asked: "Does Student have a no-args constructor". However, from your paste, __no it does not__.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Maybe you should check it because if I didn't used id(or I delete intentionally it gives error and doesn't event start) you meant no-arg constructor (@NoArgsConstructor right? then it has)

Comment: That might be a problem with Lombok (which you should have mentioned) not being executed during compilation or producing conflicts with Hibernate but if you have a look at where the exception is thrown you'll see that Hibernate has trouble locating the no-args constructor: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tuple/PojoInstantiator.java. So from Hibernate's PoV it's not there. Try to add it manually to remove the possibility of Lombok messing it up.